# Bigquery Does not cache subqueries?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables, TODAYDUID which changes a lot, and
                   UNITARCHIVE changes only once a day.

i tried this simple query

```
SELECT duid FROM `test-187010.aemodataset.TODAYDUID` where date(settlementdate)=current_date('+10:00')
UNION ALL
SELECT duid FROM `test-187010.ReportingDataset.UNITARCHIVE`
```

once I run the query, and tried it second time the cache is not used at all ?

I understand the first sub query from the table TODAYDUID  can not be cached as it is using current_date and it did change anyway, but the second one I expected to be cached.

my workaround currently, is to import the queries separately and append them at the BI tool level, is there a better approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's only one query here, and as you note it contains a `current_date()`, which makes it non-cacheable.

If you're optimizing tables for BI Engine, it might be better to:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `p.d.t_for_bi`
AS

SELECT duid FROM `test-187010.aemodataset.TODAYDUID` where date(settlementdate)=current_date('+10:00')
UNION ALL
SELECT duid FROM `test-187010.ReportingDataset.UNITARCHIVE` 
#or whatever query
```

And point your dashboards to the `p.d.t_for_bi` table.

Comment: By only one query, do you mean the whole query? Will it be correct to say that bigquery won't cache the subquery "SELECT duid FROM `test-187010.ReportingDataset.UNITARCHIVE` ". What if I create temp table of this subquery at the top and reference that in this subquery, will it start using cached temp table, when we re-run it immediately?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for the lack of caching with `CURRENT_DATE`, you can declare a variable and use it in the query. As long as the variable's value is the same, the query will be cached:

```sql
DECLARE target_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE('+10:00');

SELECT duid FROM `test-187010.aemodataset.TODAYDUID` where date(settlementdate)=target_date
UNION ALL
SELECT duid FROM `test-187010.ReportingDataset.UNITARCHIVE`
```